# What does top X% this month/this quarter/this year/overall mean?

Tags: support

Looking at any specific user at Users menu, one would observe an statement declaring the following:

top x% this month

top y% this quarter

top z% this year

or

top k% overall

What does these statements mean? top k% overall of what?

What criteria is it based on?

Can somebody elaborate on and explain these statements?

Answer (score 2):

These statements are based on reputation of a single user. When someone up- or downvotes an answer or a question the reputation of one or more users changes. StackExchange maintains a list of user reputations. This is divided into

- [weekly reputation league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/263/week/tor)
- [monthly reputation league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/263/month/tor)
- [quarterly reputation league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/263/quarter/tor)
- [yearly reputation league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/263/year/tor)
- [alltime reputation league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/263/alltime/tor)

You can see who has best reputation within a period. On each page there is a small table on the right hand-side which shows you the reputation change in terms of users. I think the 'top X% this PERIOD' numbers comes from a calculation using numbers from this table.

Comment: During PERIOD, X% of users had greater or equal reputation gain than you.